# How can I run a lm model on a list of datasets?

Tags: r

I have 9 different datasets with same variables. I added them all in a list.
Now I was to apply lm model on all the datasets in a list via for loops. I am having difficulty in splitting the data for testing.

````
for(i in data_list){

  train = i[1: nrow(i)-444, ]
  test = i[593:616,]

  daily_lm <- lm(load ~ Daily, data = datatrain)
  test$forecastlm_d <- list(predict(daily_lag_lm, test)
}```

How do I train and predict data so that it is in accordance with each dataset?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could loop over the sequence of `list` while initiating a `list` to store the output of predictions

```
preds <- vector('list', length(data_list))
for(i in seq_along(data_list)){
      tmpdat <- data_list[[i]]
      train <- tmpdat[1:(nrow(tmpdat)-444),]
      test <- tmpdat[593:616,]
      daily_lm <- lm(load ~ Daily, data = train)
      preds[[i]] <-   predict(daily_lm, test)



  }
```

---

Or another option is `lapply`

```
preds <- lapply(data_list, function(dat) {
           train <- dat[1:(nrow(dat) - 444),]
           test <- dat[593:616,]
           daily_lm <- lm(load ~ Daily, data = train)
           predict(daily_lm, test)

         })
```

Comment: It works! Thank you.
But is there a way to store predictions against time and daily data for each dataset?

Comment: @A1194 that part is not clear to me as there is no example to test.  If you can post a new question with a small reproducible example, it would be great. thanks

Comment: can you please explain why did you use seq_along?

Comment: @A1194 Reason is that I can use that as index for subsetting other objects i.e. 'preds'